# Android: Convert ListActivity into ListFragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

Hello I am using the tutorial from androidhive for working with MySQL and so on.

I want to use the following activity as a fragment - but I have to transfer the ListActivity into ListFragment - when I just change the extend from ListActivity to ListFragment different error appear

```
AllProductsActivity.java
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {
 
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
 
    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
 
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;
 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);
 
        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 
        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
 
        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();
 
        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();
 
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
 
                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
 
    }
 
    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
 
    }
 
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
 
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
 
        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
 
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
 
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
 
                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
 
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
 
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
 
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
 
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 
            return null;
        }
 
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
 
        }
 
    }
}
```

What I have to change, so I can use that as a fragment?

Edit:

i tried to change the code a little bit following some tutorials on the web...
now it works better, but there is still some problems with onPostExecute...
the doInBackground gets all parameters from mysql. i can track that with debug, but somehow after doInBackground it get's there is an error..

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListFragment {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Hashmap for ListView

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_products, container, false);

    }

    /**
        * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
        * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
            * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
            * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
            * getting All products from url
            * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
            
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
            * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                        * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                        * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show errors? logcat..

Answer (score 2):

You must create fragment in FragmentActivity. All code you need is below

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity);

        int index=0;
        MyListFragment f = MyListFragment.newInstance(index);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mylist, f);
        ft.commit();

    }//end oncreate


}//end activity
```

Layout fragment_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyListFragment.java

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment  {


    public static MyListFragment newInstance(int index) {
        MyListFragment f = new MyListFragment();

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_mylist, container, false);
        
        //read products from web and list
        //productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //new LoadProducts().execute();

        
        return v;

    }
    //end oncreateview
    


    class LoadProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


        }

    }
    //end LoadProducts



}
```

layout_mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:text="some text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white"
        android:textColor="@drawable/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```